# Postgis/Postgresql : unable to delete, view or update a spatial table

Tags: postgresql, postgis, qgis

In my student project, I need to import my shapefile in Postgis/Postgresql from QGIS. This process, I made this numerous times and I didn't have problems before.

But nowadays, I try to import two shapefile in Postgresql and Postgis :

```
Table "Structure" (Points)
contains 59 rows and 7 columns. 
This table has NULL values and an id as primary key
id_strc integer [PK]
exploit varchar
transfo varchar
water varchar
animals integer
type varchar
activity varchar 
details varchar



Table "Parcels" (Polygons)
contains 17.000 rows and 10 columns 
This table has NULL values and an id as primary key
code_cult varchar
code_group varchar
id_parcel integer [PK]
id_strc
bio varchar
src_geom varchar
occ_sol varchar
exploit varchar 
hectares real
info varchar
```

When I imported Structure and Parcels with Db Manager on QGIS, it took a while and QGIS became unresponsive. So, I use "export to Postgresql" in QGIS tool but this is the same except it's loading forever. In last resort, I tried Shp2psql and it worked. But problems began here.

For "Parcels" for instance, I can't update, neither view the table, neither drop the table. When I want to view the table or even the 100 first rows, it's loading again and again. I can't update because it take so much time and can't drop this table. Even if I want to drop the schema, it takes forever.

For the moment, I wanted to add indexes but I want to delete table in my base in first. For information, I waited more of 1 hours to drop table but it didn't worked.

I connected my base to Postgis in QGIS but this is the same than Postgresql.

But I want to know why my two shapefile are slowing Postgis or Postgresql. I don't understand, what did I do wrong?

EDIT:

With :

> DROP SCHEMA nameschema ;

[time for drop schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hf8nB.png)

And it loads again.

Comment: Are there other processes accessing the database? Sometimes other processes have transactions open that block commands which modify the structure of the database like `DROP TABLE` and the like.

Comment: Hello. Finally, I find out why it didn't work. It's because I worked with an distant DB thanks to a VPN. The network was pretty bad. Now, I work in local and it works.

Comment: Very good! And I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. Did you know that you can post an answer to your own question? This lets other people with a similar problem know that they can find a working solution here.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late, I added an anwser.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to have read my subject and sorry for the late.

My problem has been solved.

A reminder of the situation :

- I worked with a VPN with a distant DB for my work
- When I wanted to import my shapefile by PostGIS, it was loading forever
- When I imported my layer in PostgreSQL, I was unable to delete, view and update table
- Some functions was very very slow

How I solved this?

The solution is to work in a local DB and the loading/slow was gone.

Why this problem existed?

Possibly because the network was bad or the connection was bad too.

But it's possible some process was ongoing.